# How to check if UITextField text is empty when done editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I currently have a UITextField with default text and set to clear when editing begins.  I'm trying to make it so that if the field is empty or nil when editing is done the text value will be the default text again.  I'm having trouble detecting when either editing is done or the keyboard is dismissed.  Could anyone tell me which detection method I would want to use and how to implement it?  Thanks so much!

---

### Edit

---

A `placeholder` can't be used in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't need to handle "default text" yourself. Check `placeholder` property of [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) class.

**Update**

So `placeholder` is not good for your case. Did you try to implement [`UITextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate) methods for your `UITextField` and change the text in `textViewDidEndEditing:`?

To do so, implement `UITextFieldDelegate` methods those look useful for your scenario in your view controller, and set `delegate` of your `UITextField` to the view controller (either by Interface Builder or programmatically). Set the default text in `textViewDidEndEditing:` method.

You can refer to the "Getting the Entered Text and Setting Text" section of [Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html).

Comment: Yeah, I actually need to have the default text there because it's value is used right after editing, I can't just use a placeholder for this.  I tried that but our client didn't want that :)

Comment: Added a link to official documentation about managing text fields.

Answer (score 13):

you have to use the textfield delegate

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

in this delegate make check like this

```
if ( [textField.text length] == 0 )
{
    // the text field is empty do your work
} else {
    ///  the text field is not empty 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string
{
    if (range.location == 0 && string.length == 0)
    {
        //textField is empty
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the user highlights a subset of the text that starts from the 0 index and then deletes.

Comment: @AlexisCandelaria, I have posted one more answer

Answer (score 2):

When you get the delegate call for when the text field returns, use the `sender` parameter to check the text (`sender.text`), and if it is equal to `@""` set your default text.

Answer (score 2):

I use 2 approaches. My choice depends on the application business logic.

1) I check the resulting text after applying changes in `shouldChangeCharactersIn`:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        var text = textField.text ?? ""

        let startIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
        let endIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location + range.length)
        text = text.replacingCharacters(in: startIndex..<endIndex, with: string)
        if text.count == 0 {
            // textField is empty
        } else {
            // textField is not empty
        }
        return true
    }
```

2) I use `editingChanged` action:

```
@IBAction private func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if (sender.text?.count ?? 0) == 0 {
            // textField is empty
        } else {
            // textField is not empty
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to check wether the deleted range is the entire length of the text.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:  NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if !(range.location == 0 && string.count == 0 && range.length == textField.text?.count) {
      // Text field is empty
    }
    return true
}
```